# What is the best way of resting for the noon in office?

Tags: health, sleep

I work in an office that has no room for a bed to take a nap. But I feel real sleepy after lunch and feel tired in the afternoon, is there any good way of resting for the noon in an typical office without bed ?

Comment: Can anyone explain why they think this question is on-topic and thus worth upvoting? Because while I'm sure everybody would love to take a nap at work, its not exactly related to exercise

Comment: Perhaps this could find a place on the [Personal Productivity](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange? (but I voted to close as off-topic for now, as it's not within the scope of this site)

Comment: i vote for this to be close too as it is off topic.

Comment: I'm closing the question as off-topic for now. People are welcome to edit the question to be on-topic (see the [faq] for examples). Reopening the question is simple to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it really depends on your office environment.  For example, do you have your own office where no one can see you or are you in a cubicle?

If your office culture is ok with you taking a nap, then simply put your head down on your desk.  [According to research](http://lifehacker.com/5897352/a-quick-nap-can-boost-your-cognitive-ability-but-only-when-timed-just-right), the nap should only be 15-20 mins between 1-3pm.

If naps are frowned upon, then you can take a nap in your car.  You may have to drive a bit and park your car where you won't be seen.

An alternative is to use other methods to re-energize yourself.  Taking a walk or drinking water may help.  More tricks can be found [here](http://www.health.com/health/gallery/0,,20567286,00.html).

Answer (score 1):

I take a nap at work several days a week. Usually I lie on the floor, sometimes just rest my head on the desk.